# get max value using checkbox selections

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, maxifs

I am trying to implement a function in google sheets that will provide the max value from a set of values in column B based on the corresponding checkbox in column C.

I was able to get the sum to work using:

```
=sumif(C3:C7, TRUE, B3:B7)
```

However, I am not having any luck finding the max value of the set.

Answer (score 0):

try `MAXIFS`

```
=MAXIFS(B3:B7, C3:C7, TRUE)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

or you can `FILTER` it:

```
=MAX(FILTER(B3:B7, C3:C7=TRUE))
```

[image: 0]